# When typecasting to a char in C, which bytes are used to make the character?

Tags: c, char, casting

When you typecast from an int to a char, you are cutting down the number of bytes used from 4 to 1. How does it pick which byte it is going to use make the char?

Does it take the most significant byte?

Or does it take the least significant?

Or is there some sort of rule I should know about?

Comment: I would bet that this is undefined behaviour, but don't take my word for it.

Comment: LSB of course.  Endianness doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C will take the least-significant byte when doing a narrowing conversion, so if you have the integer value 0xCAFEBABE and you convert it to a char, you'll get the value 0xBE.

Of course, there's no actual guarantee that an `int` is four bytes or that a `char` is one, but I'm pretty sure that the logic for doing the truncation will always be the same and will just drop the higher-order bits that don't fit into the `char`.

Comment: It helps to think of `char` as the smallest of the integer types, rather than as a type for characters.  If you cast from `int` to `short` (assume `sizeof(int) > sizeof(short)`), of course it takes the low bits of the value; the same is true for casts to `char`.

Comment: keep in mind that implementations are free to raise a signal on narrowing signed conversions if the value can't be represented in the new type; unsigned convversions, however, are always well-defined...

Comment: Actually, there is a guarantee that a `char` is one byte.

Answer (score 2):

If `char` is signed, it's implementation-defined unless the original value already fits in the range of values for `char`. An implementation is completely free to generate nonsense (or raise a signal) if it doesn't fit. If `char` is unsigned (which the standard allows), then the value is reduced modulo `1<<CHAR_BIT` (usually 256).